# Criar um contador regressivo (countdown) partir de input e memorizar no localStorage

Tags: javascript, countdown

Como podem ver no meu exemplo abaixo, eu tenho um formulário que joga os dados escritos nas entradas (`input`) no html e os mesmos são armazenados no localStorage.

No `input=date` eu preciso que a data fornecida seja transformada em um contador regressivo (`countdown`), para os dias restantes.

```
<form id="form">
    <label>Name:</label>        <input type="text" id="name"><br>
    <label>Deadline:</label>    <input type="date" id="deadline"><br>
    <label>Image:</label>       <input type="file" id="pic">
    <input id="create" type="button" value="Create" />
</form>
<div id="tbody"></div>

<script>
$(function(){
$('#create').click(function () {
    var theName = $('#name').val();
    var theDeadline = $('#deadline').val();
    var pic = document.getElementById("pic").files[0];
    var imgUrl;
    var reader = new FileReader();  
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var imgURL = reader.result;
      $('#tbody').prepend("<div>" + theName + "<br>" + theDeadline + "<br><img src=" + imgURL + "></div>");

      var tbody = $('#tbody').html();
      localStorage.setItem('tbody', tbody);
      saveDataToLocalStorage(imgURL);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(pic);
    return false;
});

$('#tbody').html(localStorage.getItem('tbody'));
return false;
});
</script>
```

versão de exemplo no jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7qtk9gyh/

Gostei bastante do puglin *jquery.countdown.js*, é bem simples, porém, como sou novo com scripts, não sei mesmo como fazê-lo funcionar partir de um input e combinado com o formulário. Qualquer ajuda é muuuito bem-vinda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode transformar seus inputs de data em milissegundos e calcular a diferença entre eles

```js
const date1 = new Date('8/1/2019'); // M/d/yyyy
const date2 = new Date(new Date().toDateString()); // cria uma data desconsiderando os milisegundos
const diffTime = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
console.log(`Data 1 = ${date1}`); 
console.log(`Data 2 = ${date2}`); 
console.log(`Diferença de tempo = ${diffTime}`); 
console.log(`Diferença de dias = ${diffDays}`);
```

Então, como você quer armazenar no local storage o resultado da diferença, seria necessário apenas adicionar ao final do código

```js
localStorage.setItem('countdown', diffDays)
```

Comment: Amigo, eu tenho dificuldade em como implementar o que me passou, sou muito novo nisso. Você poderia me passar o exemplo no fiddle?

Comment: Criei [esse fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6y7f3hz2/) com a implementação no seu código. Removi todo o código que não é pertinente à lógica da data. Sugiro que faça isso para simplificar suas futuras perguntas, deixando apenas exemplificado o que realmente precisa de ajuda.

Comment: Primeiramente, muito obrigado. Eu achei importante deixar o exemplo mais completo pra que entendessem melhor como funciona o contexto. Por ex., preciso que o contador crie-se em conjunto com o funcionamento do formulário. Na tua solução eu não consigo "pegar" o countdown junto das outras variáveis - alí quando escrevo elementos pelo .prepend. e uso os valores dinamicamente (ex: "<a>" + varX +"</a>") -, porque é bem necessário que seja possível criar-se mais de um countdown, um em cada clique em "create", assim como todo resto, e não apenas substituí-lo.

Comment: Penso que seria preciso que houvesse só uma armazenação no localStorage, que é a do todo, "tbody" do exemplo. Infelizmente eu não tenho conhecimento suficiente pra tentar fazer isso por conta própria  :(

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra, criei [mais esse fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joxpywsk/10/) contendo algumas implementações que podem vir a te ajudar, incluindo a do salvamento total do local storage. Para qualquer coisa além disso, sugiro que levante dúvidas separadas como "como salvar HTML no localStorage", "como contar a diferença entre datas". Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: @ThiagoSoubra, conseguiu?

Comment: Desculpa a demora, acabei tendo que me dedicar aos estudos. Eu ainda não pude testar pra valer, mas o que você me passou é ótimo e bem explicado

Comment: Muito obrigado!!